# Can you help me form this answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

After this question: [Are limes and lime juice more acidic than lemons and lemon juice?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/are-limes-and-lime-juice-more-acidic-than-lemons-and-lemon-juice), I decided that some experimentation was in order.

My experimentation isn't exactly on point, I'm not testing acidity, I am (was) testing the relative effectiveness of various acids in preventing browning. So I wrote a question. It's a good question, I like the question.

I did the experiment.

I am blown away by the results. They make no sense. I am shocked, but here it is. In the case of **diced** avocados; lime juice, lemon juice, vinegar and Fruit Fresh *all* make matters worse. I kept track of the method and I've got the pictures. So now what??

My answer, based on my experimentation only begs a larger question. WTF??

How can I word that?

My answer (based on the experimentation) does in fact answer my original question, but now I have a bigger question. But...that leaves me asking a question in an answer.

The experiment is interesting enough that I don't want to screw it up. Advice?

**EDIT**: I think know what I'm going do. It kind of sucks, but I think I'm just going to post a question, basically asking, WTF? This is weirder than my ice tray. If you've got a better idea, I'm still all ears, but I think I have no answer at this point. Just a different question. Before I write that question, I will repeat the experiment with mashed avocado.

Comment: They do still work on other things, right??

Comment: @Jefromi Yep. After 24 hours all of my treated fruit other than avocado looks OK, the untreated is a bit brown. The best looking avocado (though decidedly brown at this point) is the untreated. The vinegar one is almost black. I'm just floored about it!

Comment: @Jefromi I'm 6 hours into the mashed avocado version. Do you remember the scene in Independence Day (maybe it was Contact), when the scientist was asked, "How do you know?"  That's kind if how I feel right now. "Cause it's slowing down." This can't be right, yet it is.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I'd just ask a question about why it happens, though it might be a hard one to answer!

You could possibly also ask and answer a question about how to prevent avocado from browning, since this is certainly good to know, though it might be better if you had proactive advice, not just "don't put acid on it". In that case you could just link to the "why" question from your answer.